# How to combine exact match query with text search query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-dsl

My Exact match query on fields status, location_id  looks like below:

```
{'query': {'constant_score': {'filter': {'bool': {
     'must': [{'bool': {'should': [{'terms': {'status': ['Open', 'not complete']}}]}},
              {'bool': {'should': [{'terms': {'location_id': [1652]}}]}}],
     'must_not': []}}}},
 'sort': [{'id': {'order': 'asc', 'unmapped_type': 'long'}}]}
```

Suppose above query returns 50 records, now in this 50 records I want search a word in one of the column. For example column is description and word is "test". How can I combine above query with this search word query.
Search column can be one from must query(status/location)

In short I want all the records having status Open/Not complete and location_id == 1652 and descreption field having word "test" anywhere in the text

I tried [simple_query_String](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-simple-query-string-query.html) and [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) but I was getting error. Not sure where I can put it in above nested query.

I tried below query with **match** but it writtens no records:

```
{'query': {'constant_score': {'filter': {'bool': {
     'must': [{'bool': {'should': [{'terms': {'status': ['Open', 'not complete']}}]}},
              {'bool': {'should': [{'terms': {'location_id': [1652]}}]}},
              {'bool': {'should': [{'match': {'description': 'test'}}]}}],
     'must_not': []}}}},
 'sort': [{'id': {'order': 'asc', 'unmapped_type': 'long'}}]}
```

Working Query using **query_string**

```
{'query': {'constant_score': {'filter': {'bool': {
     'must': [{'bool': {'should': [{'terms': {'status': ['Open', 'not complete']}}]}},
              {'bool': {'should': [{'terms': {'location_id': [1652]}}]}},
              {'query_string': {"default_field": "description",
                                "query": "*test*"}}],
     'must_not': []}}}},
 'sort': [{'id': {'order': 'asc', 'unmapped_type': 'long'}}]}
```

Comment: which elasticsearch version you are using?

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Yes, tried your answer and added updated query in question. But still it was not working with *match* query. Tried with *wildcard* and *query_string*, its working now but query is case sensitive. Wanted to make it case insensitive

Comment: @BhavyaGupta Version is 5.6.16

Comment: it would be great if you can add some sample data, on which you are performing your search query

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) where

> A query matches documents matching boolean combinations of other
> queries.

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result.
The below search query is for your following requirements:

> In short I want all the records having status Open/Not complete and
> location_id == 1652 and descreption field having word "test" anywhere
> in the text

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "description":"test",
  "status":["open","not connected"],
  "location_id":[1652]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "description": "test"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "status": [
              "open",
              "not complete"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "location_id": [
              "1652"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_63936644",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 2.287682,
        "_source": {
          "description": "test",
          "status": [
            "open",
            "not connected"
          ],
          "location_id": [
            1652
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Tried the match query but it didn't returned any results even if there are matching records. I have added query in question that I tried

Comment: @GauravVichare as you mentioned in the question, do you want all the records having status Open/Not complete and location_id == 1652 and description field having word "test"

Comment: @GauravVichare can you give any sample index data on which you are trying to query, because the data on which I tested with my given search query works fine, and I am able to get the result